# Why one of two identical Google Sheets runs so much slower than the other

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet consisting of IMPORTXML functions (among others) as the decision basis for some dependent Zapier functions with a 3rd application, which has been running increasingly slower. This has downstream issues to the cascading schedule of systems I use thereafter, and not to mention mis-triggers to Zapier as it tries to catch up with changing cell values, as the formulas run.

I've tried to optimise what I can in it, to get it to run faster. One step I took, was to clone the original sheet for the purpose of testing optimisations on the clone (essentially staging sheet).

What I've noticed in doing this, is that the clone sheet runs all the included formulas sooooo much quicker than its identical twin original, like soooo much quicker.

Just wondering if anyone knows of some obvious reasons why this would be happening, and what I can do to get the original running as fast as the clone?

Comment: it may sound strange but GS actually has versions. if you created a spreadsheet some time ago in the meantime some things could be optimized in the latest version so stuff runs faster on the copy. the same way there are things that work on older spreadsheets but not on new ones like smart-text-overflow or row-auto-adjustment.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know as a potential cause. If I don't get any other ideas I may have to consider this. However, I wonder if there might there be a way to upgrade the original to Google's latest version? If not I have to swap out all my systems references to the Google Sheet, which would be very laborious.

Comment: By any chance, was your original file shared with other users? If so, there is a chance that the original file would run slower than the clone since other users might be using the original file as well (compared to the clone with you as the sole user).

Comment: Nope, hasn't been shared with anyone. I'm of a mind to swap everything to the new sheet but just want to avoid being in the same place in a few months time, not knowing the underlying cause.